# Converting a jQuery fadeIn() fadeOut checkbox to radio button

Tags: javascript, html

I had this code working for a yes no checkbox, but stupidly obviously they can both be checked. I want to use radio buttons, however, yes is highlighted straight away the element is still hidden.

What I want is EITHER:

For the element to load with the page because it automatically selects yes and another element to be shown if 'no' is selected

OR:

None to be selected initially on the radio group. Let the user click either (but not both). Amoplished either with Radio or Checkbox (jQuery).

Here is the code for the show/hide for the first element.

```
$('#common_restaurant_seperate_sittings_yes').click(function(){
  if($('#common_restaurant_seperate_sittings_yes').is(':checked')) {
    $('#opening_times_seperate_sittings').fadeIn(700);
  } else {
    $('#opening_times_seperate_sittings').fadeOut(700);   
  }
});
```

˚

```
<div id="opening_times_seperate_sittings">content</div>


<input type="radio" class="checkbox_style" name="common_restaurant_seperate_sittings_yes" id="common_restaurant_seperate_sittings_yes" label="Yes" />

<input type="radio" class="checkbox_style" name="common_restaurant_seperate_sittings_yes" id="common_restaurant_seperate_sittings_no" label="No" />
```

Comment: Could you provide a Fiddle?

Comment: Post a complete code example in your question please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I do not know your HTML, I assumed it would briefly look something like this:

```
<input type="radio" class="yesNo" value="yes" name="yesNo"/> Yes
<input type="radio" class="yesNo" value="no" name="yesNo"/> No
<div id="opening_times_seperate_sittings">This content is only to be shown when Yes is selected</div>
```

Now, since you want to use radio buttons, you can group them, allowing only one of them to be selected at a time. Then, as you already have in your code, js would look like this:

```
$('.yesNo').on('click', function(){
  if($(this).val() == 'yes') {
      $('#opening_times_seperate_sittings').fadeIn(700);
  } else {
      $('#opening_times_seperate_sittings').fadeOut(700);   
  }
});
```

and here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/35gwgtjL/1/

**Update:**

```
If "Yes" is selected by default, you can add a check on your page load to check if Yes is selected:

if($('.yesNo[value="yes"]').attr('checked')=='checked'){
  $('#opening_times_seperate_sittings').show();
}
```

Update fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/35gwgtjL/2/

Note: On the fiddle, if you remove this js code, even "Yes" is selected by default, it will not display the content div.

Comment: I know this already. But will this display the element straight away? Because the first element is selected in a radio and the element in my code doesnt display on page load...

Comment: Which element in your code is not displayed on page load?

Comment: #opening_times_seperate_sittings

Comment: would be ideal to use checkboxes. but only allow one checkbox to selected. Any thoughts about that?

Comment: It does not really matter what you use. Either checkbox or radio button would do the job. If the 'yes' is selected by default and you would like to display the `#opening_times_seperate_sittings`, you can add a check on the page load to see if it is checked. Please see the edit in the answer.